# VS How To Enable XAML Visual Editor for Xaml files (outside of WPF project)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin

Visual Studio Community 2015. Xamarin Test Project. 
I have a project which have some layouts - Layout.xaml

It shows the designer - it looks like an XML editor of some sort - but what I am looking for is the Visual Xaml Designer - where you see the results of what you do.

If you open any WPF project you will and doulbe click any of its default Xaml files - you will see a nice looking Xaml Visual and Code Editor combined. How can I enable the same within my Xamarin project?

Why Xaml that is in WPF project shows that nice Visual Editor and Xamarin Project does not? Is there a way to bind it?

It has to depend on the project type I assume.

PS: I have a droid project and the iOS and a portable library where I have those XAML files.

If you have any more questions - please ask.

**Update**

I tried installing Microsoft.Xaml (through Nuget Package manager) - still no luck

**Update 2**

I create a basic WPF project and look at its references. I matched it identically with my project - but still no luck

**Update 3**

WPF Project has different properties (which makes sense)

```
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

And my XAML files have these

```
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

Even though I knew manipulating those would not launch Xaml Visual Designer - still tried that with no luck.

**What loads this XAML Visual Designer for the WPF project????**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is the answer - there is a Xamarin.Forms Previewer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/)

> Use the **View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer** menu in Visual Studio to open the preview window. Use the Window > New Vertical Tab Group menu to position it side-by-side.

Comment: I hope that saves you a couple hours. I almost reinvented the wheel the way I was heading! Love the community - peace & love to you my brothers & sisters!

Comment: For anyone using VS2017 it is just called Forms Previewer now.

Comment: Default VS installs JDK x86, but de x64 is required for the Forms Previewer to work, so you'll have to install x64 and change it in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct possibility for a preview of your XAML-views, but you can use Gorilla Player(http://gorillaplayer.com/) a software which allows a such function

Comment: Then what is this XAML Previewer? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

Comment: It's okay for a very simple view. What if your view is depending on binding, templates etc.